# Why might debian become unresponsive with virtually 0% CPU usage?

Tags: debian, debian-squeeze

We have a problem with one of our (virtual) Debian servers failing in a strange way.  *The server will stop responding to to the network (no SSH, no Ping response, no app response).*  The only way we can gain access is through the virtual-host providers console login (which simulates keyboard access).  During this time the CPU usage is practically 0% (In fact I can see when it happened from the CPU usage graph - it goes from it's normal ~5% usage to 0%.)

This has happened a few times now seemingly randomly, and the server never experiences high load.  We are running Debian Squeeze.

I've ruled out problems with the virtual machines' physical host (we've moved to a different physical host, and are still seeing this problem).

Does anyone have any ideas about how to diagnose this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like a misconfigured network, either on the VM itself or on the provider itself...

Comment: Any messages in kern.log or syslog?

Comment: @AndrewSchulman I don't see anything in kern.log or syslog that looks like an error.